# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' : prblem with NumPy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.x, floating-point

I am pretty new to Python.I know this error occurs when one tries to multiply a string with a fraction i.e float. In my case , I can't figure out how can a numpy floating point array be a string. Here's complete the code.

```
#!usr/bin/python

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from numpy import *

# Declaration of constants

K = 3.14159265359
N= 10
p_za=[]
pv_za_temp=[]
#-----------------------
#Allotment of particles
#-----------------------

p_initial = np.linspace(0,2,num=10)

pv_za_temp.append(np.array(p_initial))

print pv_za_temp

#Displacement of particles using Zeldovich Approximation
def t_range(start, end, step):
  while start <= end:
    yield start
    start += step

for t in t_range(0,1,0.1):
  print t
  p_za=[]
  pv_za=[]
  # Opening file in file_t format
  fname = 'file_' + str(t) + '.dat'
  fo = open(fname,'w')

# p_za.append(p_initial - t*K*np.sin(K*p_initial))
  pv_za.append(K*np.sin(K*pv_za_temp))
  pv_za_temp = []
  pv_za_temp.append(np.array(pv_za))
```

The line that is showing error is :

```
pv_za.append(K*np.sin(K*pv_za_temp))
```

I can't figure out the problem. When this line shows error, the line above it works out perfectly well. The error message is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ZA.py", line 40, in <module>
    pv_za.append(K*np.sin(K*pv_za_temp))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pv_za_temp` is an ordinary Python list, which doesn't support scalar multiplication. You need a NumPy array, which you can create from a complete list by using

```
pv_za_temp = np.array(pv_za_temp)
```

Note that `.array` doesn't support `.append`. Either build the list completely in advance, or use `hstack` or `vstack` as appropriate.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ZA.py", line 22, in <module>
    pv_za_temp.append(np.array(p_initial))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`  This error is showing up when trying to convert the list to NumPy array just after the declaration `pv_za_temp = []`

Comment: Yeah...that could be overcome using `pv_za_temp = np.array(p_initial)` :)

Comment: This is slight diversion from the topic. I don't know if I'm supposed to start a new thread or not. How to write NumPy floating point arrays to file? This is the error I'm getting `fo.write('{0:f}  {1:f} \n'.format(np.array(p_initial),np.array(pv_za))) 
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`