# ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, string-formatting

I get the following error when trying to write 2 NumPy arrays on a DAT file.

```
fo.write('{0:f} {1:f} \n'.format(np.array(p_initial),np.array(pv_za)))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

The full code is available here : [TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' : prblem with NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804936/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float-prblem-with-nump/15804979?noredirect=1#15804979)

I am quite new to Python. How does one write NumPy floating point arrays to DAT files so that they can be plotted using matplotlib or gnuplot ?

Comment: NumPy doesn't support `.format()` formatting yet, I don't think. NumPy also has *dedicated* support for writing arrays to files, why invent your own?

Comment: Seems to me that `np.array(p_initial)` and `np.array(pv_za)` are strings, not floats.

Comment: @InbarRose: No, they are converted to strings because they do not have a `__format__` hook.

Comment: ...so they are strings... at least when they get to the part of the code that wants to use them as floats.

Comment: So, isn't there any way out???

Comment: numpy.savetext() will do,I suppose?

Comment: ...but I wanna store 2 array to the file. numpy.savetxt will allow only one! :(

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I've been Googleing to try to find more info about NumPy not having a `__format__` hook, but have found nothing. Do newer versions support it? Can you link me to more info? Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of any NumPy version that supports `__format__`. I only stated that the OP can't do what he wants to do because that method is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way with `numpy.savetxt`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)
b = np.arange(5) + 2
np.savetxt('test.txt', np.array([a,b]).T, '%f')
```

Gives:

```
0.000000 2.000000
1.000000 3.000000
2.000000 4.000000
3.000000 5.000000 
4.000000 6.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try following approach:

```
import itertools as i
import numpy as np
>>> '{0:f} {1:f}'.format(*i.chain(np.array([123]), np.array([234])))
'123.000000 234.000000'
```

Comment: Please provide me information why my answer after edition isn't useful.

Comment: I didn't vote down your answer Marcin!... That error is not showing.  Now I get the error again I was having `pv_za.append(K*np.sin(K*pv_za_temp))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` :((

Comment: That doesn't work because the OP wants to print the entire arrays in one line, not array elements.